# Quagga bgp advertisment stop after peer reboot

Tags: networking, freebsd

I am using quagga and FreeBSD boxes to achieve this: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/border-gateway-protocol-bgp/13762-40.html#conf3. Only change is that upstream provider is sending full bgp instead of the default route.

I have everything set up and working moreless correctly. However, I am having issues with few things:

- when connection between R101 and R103 goes down, R101 doesn't send traffic over R102-R104 link. This is because, R101 doesn't have any routes R102 besides the one I am advertising. How should I can configure quagga to redistribute routes obtained via external peer over internal BGP session?
- For advertising my networks, Quagga works until the moment I restart R101. Once, R!01 comes back and internal BGP session is re-established, R102 stops advertising anything to R101, but advertises to R104. Is this normal? After I restart quagga on R102, the advertising to R101 works correctly.

Quagga config from R101:

```
!
hostname Router
log file /var/log/quagga.log
log stdout
hostname bgpd
bgp config-type cisco
!
debug bgp updates in
!
password zebra
enable password zebra
!
interface bge0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface bge1
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface igb0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface igb1
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface igb2
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface igb3
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface lagg0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface lo0
 no link-detect
!
interface lo1
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface pfsync0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan3
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan4
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan5
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan101
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan106
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan107
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan109
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
router bgp 1
 no synchronization
 bgp router-id 0.0.0.1
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 1.0.0.0
 network 2.0.0.0
 neighbor 4.4.4.1 remote-as 2
 neighbor 4.4.4.1 description "R101 uplink"
 neighbor 4.4.4.1 update-source 4.4.4.2
 neighbor 4.4.4.1 send-community both
 neighbor 4.4.4.1 route-map R1-MAP out
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 remote-as 1
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 description "R101 BGP interconnect"
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 update-source 1.1.1.2
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 next-hop-self
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 send-community both
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 soft-reconfiguration inbound
 maximum-paths 2
 no auto-summary
!
ip prefix-list 1 seq 5 permit 2.0.0.0/8
ip prefix-list 2 seq 5 permit 1.0.0.0/8
!
route-map R1-MAP permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list 1
 set as-path prepend 1 1 1
!
route-map R1-MAP permit 20
 match ip address prefix-list 2
!
ip forwarding
!
line vty
!
end
```

R102 full config:

```
hostname Router
hostname bgpd
log file /var/log/quagga.log
log stdout
bgp config-type cisco
!
password zebra
enable password zebra
!
interface bge0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface bge1
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface igb0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface igb1
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface igb2
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface igb3
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface lagg0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface lo0
 no link-detect
!
interface lo1
 no link-detect
!
interface pfsync0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan3
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan4
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan5
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan101
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan106
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan107
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
interface vlan109
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
 no link-detect
!
router bgp 1
 no synchronization
 bgp router-id 0.0.0.2
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 1.0.0.0
 network 2.0.0.0
 neighbor 3.3.3.1 remote-as 2
 neighbor 3.3.3.1 description "R102 uplink"
 neighbor 3.3.3.1 update-source 3.3.3.2
 neighbor 3.3.3.1 send-community both
 neighbor 3.3.3.1 route-map R102-MAP out
 neighbor 1.1.1.2 remote-as 1
 neighbor 1.1.1.2 description "R102 BGP interconnect"
 neighbor 1.1.1.2 update-source 1.1.1.1
 neighbor 1.1.1.2 next-hop-self
 neighbor 1.1.1.2 send-community both
 neighbor 1.1.1.2 soft-reconfiguration inbound
 no auto-summary
!
ip prefix-list 1 seq 5 permit 1.0.0.0/8
ip prefix-list 2 seq 5 permit 2.0.0.0/8
!
route-map R102-MAP permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list 1
 set as-path prepend 1 1 1
!
route-map R102-MAP permit 20
 match ip address prefix-list 2
!
ip forwarding
!
line vty
!
end
```

Comment: Obviously they need to have static routes to the peers. It is a requirement they know that routes in other to negotiate and do their job.

Comment: Well, what are connected routes about then? Can you show me the example?